# Why can't functions with optional arguments be coerced to functions without them?

Tags: ocaml, coercion, subtyping

I have the following simple functions:

```
type t = unit -> unit

let f () = ()

let g ?opt:_ () = ()
```

With these functions defined, `(f :> t)` succeeds, but `(g :> t)` fails with the following error:

> Error: This expression cannot be coerced to `type t = unit -> unit`; it has type
>
> `?opt:'a -> unit -> unit`
>
> but is here used with `type t = unit -> unit`

It seems that the type of `g` should be a subtype of `t`. If so, why does this type coercion fail?

Comment: How would you e.g. coerce from `?opt:'a -> ?opt:'a -> unit -> unit` to  `?opt:'a -> unit -> unit`?

Comment: @JorgeAdriano I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying; what's the issue with the coercion in this case?

Comment: not suggesting there's an issue, just trying to understand how it would work. You could either omit the first or the second optional arg to get the second type.

Comment: I think the formalisation of subtyping in ocaml is something like: `x <: y` iff any function `y -> z` may be given a pointer to an `x` and still work. Obviously that is not how subtyping is specified. If I give you a pointer to a `?x -> y -> z` but you expect a `y -> z` then you will likely call it with the wrong calling convention causing an error.

Comment: @DanRobertson I don't quite follow what you're saying; if I expect a `y -> z` and you pass me a `?x -> y -> z`, you can still call it with one argument and get back a `z`.

Comment: I give you a pointer but I don’t tell you whether or not it is to a function with the optional argument. You need some machine code that will work if the function does or does not take any number of optional arguments.